# AngularJS UI-Router - When to use child/nested state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I in the process of doing a fairly big angularjs application.
Currently the design is 1 .html file per state. (Only 1 html per view. I'm trying not to include multiple html per page.)

```
$stateProvider.state('firstState', {
    url: '/customer',
    templateUrl: 'customer.html'
});

$stateProvider.state('secondState', {
    url: '/customerdetail',
    templateUrl: 'customerdetail.html'
});
```

Even though it seems like **customerdetail** state should be a child of **customer** state but i'm making them separate even though in customer.html there are links(using Ui-router params) to drill down into customerdetails.

Is it a good design as long as it fulfills my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Child states are used when you want to share section across states

Just say you want to have a section that shows the customer details on all customer states then you would have

```
<div>Shared info across all customer states</div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

And then all the child states would render in the ui-view. If you don't have any shared blocks then there is no need for child states.

Comment: By sections do you mean multiple components in the same page? For example, left hand side will have the customer name, when I click on the customer name the right hand side of the page will display the customer's details.

Comment: Anything that doesn't change on the page view to view. You put information like a customer info banner on the parent page and have the child components render in the <ui-view>